# Pillow: Image.ANTIALIAS vs Image.HAMMING

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pillow

Помогите понять, в чем разница двух опций ресайзов библиотеки Pillow в Python:
`ANTIALIAS` и `HAMMING`.

Какой из них быстрее, какой качественнее сжимает (качество - это отсутствие потерь информации).

Comment: При сжатии в принципе не может не быть потерь

Comment: @andreymal, тогда мы не смогли пользоваться архиваторами... ;)

Comment: @MaxU окей, при сжатии в контексте ресайза картинок)

Answer (score 2):

[Вот таблица сравнения качества / скорости фильтров](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#filters-comparison-table):

```
Filter      Downscaling_quality     Upscaling_quality       Performance
NEAREST                                                         *****
BOX                 *                                           ****
BILINEAR            *                       *                   ***
HAMMING             **                                          ***
BICUBIC             ***                     ***                 **
LANCZOS/ANTIALIAS   ****                    ****                *
```

Т.е. `LANCZOS` (AKA `ANTIALIAS`) самый качественный, но и самый медленный из всех фильтров.

NOTE: [The `ANTIALIAS` constant is left for backward compatibility and is an alias for `LANCZOS`.](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.7.0.html)

Comment: Это славно, но я вот сейчас запускаю NEAREST и ANTIALIAS на одинаковых картинках и сравниваю время работы - разница в одну сотую!

Comment: Вы спросили - я ответил. У меня нет причин недоверять разработчикам `Pillow`. С точки зрения математики и статистики только лишь разница ни о чем не говорит - пример: `0.0125 - 0.0025 == 0.01`